# Intellij debugger suspends before hitting any breakpoints

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm debugging a remote Java application using Intellij. I have defined several breakpoints, but Intellij suspends my application before hitting any of them. When I click 'Resume program', it continues to another arbitrary point that I did not mark. I have to do this several times until I finally get to the code I'm interested in. All of these unwanted pauses happen in library files. Is there a way to get Intellij to stop pausing at these places?

Comment: Have you tried removing all breakpoints and then adding again?  Also, have you made any changes to your code in the IDE since the last build?

Comment: Ah, removing all breakpoints seems to have worked. Thank you.